# different output rpart function in sql and Rstudio

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, rpart

i'm using the rpart function to predict whether a certain customer buys an item. the r script i wrote works and gives the desired output. i let the script run in SQL (using serialize) and it gives different output.

my colleague helped me check the the entire code and the data and came also to the conclusion that both models should give similar output. i also ran the script in rstudio and RGui and gave the same output. we also set in both models the same seed.

i'm afraid the code is to long too share and divided over multiple systems.

somebody knows what could be the problem? does sql use a different version of the rpart function? does set.seed(1234) give different output between sql and R

version rstudio: 1.2.1335
version SQL: SQL server 2016

Comment: Do note `set.seed` differs in R installs and versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out the problem. sql-server seems to run r in a 32-bit version (at least for us). I downloaded a 32-bit version of RGui and gave me the same output as the SQL output.